# what is the priority of httpd conf and htaccess files rewrite directives

Tags: php, .htaccess, httpd.conf

i need to set most of my rewrite directive inside http.conf, and only keep a redirect directive inside my htaccess in case the website was offline, because that is variable and i dont want to have to restart wamp in case the http file got changed.
but what i have concluded is that when my website has an htaccess file even if it's empty, the rewrite directive inside my httpd file are not taken into account, am i correct?
if not so, i would like to know if both files are taken into account at the same time, which one has the first priority?

Comment: 1. `httpd.conf` 2. a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: `.htaccess` can amend/alter/add whats in `httpd.conf`

Comment: If you can place all your rewite rules in the `httpd.conf` file that is the best way, as an `.htaccess` file has to be read, interpreted and actioned each time a page is accessed from the directory in which it lives, or a directory below the directory it lives in.

Comment: An empty `.htaccess` file should have no effect on the settings used in the `httpd.conf` file

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly for your reply, i need to use htaccess file as well because sometimes i would need to make the website offline i dont want to change httpd conf and restart wamp, instead just add that directive inside htaccess file. what do you think?

Comment: Thats fine. Just add as much as possible to the `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly for your reply